# AWS PermGen, increase RAM for t1.micro or reconfigure Java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I run a t1.micro on Amazon web services for a demo / test and when I deploy there is PermGen outofmemoryerror for Jetty so  I suppose that I should change the instance type but how do I do that and is it really necessary or could I make it if I assign more memory to Java? I'm running Jetty on an Ubuntu with oracle java 7 for a webapp with hibernate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its more likely that you need to increase the PermGen Memory try add this `export JAVA_OPTIONS="-XX:MaxPermSize=512m"` to your jetty.sh

Answer (score 1):

The Amazon t1.micro instance has only 0.6xx GiB memory so choose permgen size carefully and you need a very strict memory management.

The "-XX:MaxPermSize=512m" is a bit big, but you can play with the settings in smaller steps.

In java 7 permgen is storing the loaded classes, so you don't need to specify too high value for them (except you created a gigantic app :) ). The default size is 64m, but it looks like not enough to you. Increase it in 32m steps to find the proper size. When it stable and runs properly add an extra 32m to leave some extra space for longer run.

Comment: -XX:MaxPermSize as the name implies its the max allowed but not necessary what will be used. and also note that permGen space shouldn't be growing over time.

Comment: If you not determine the proper size it's easy to end-up with unnecessarily big memory reservation settings. Btw. not all classes loaded with the app startup.